# How to fetch semaphores and sharedmem objects for a specific apache instance when more than one apache instances run with the same app id on the box

Tags: apache-httpd, ipc, shared-memory, semaphore

Not sure if the question is pertinent for this forum.

We have a server with 3 apache instances running with the "same" app/functional ID

These instances communicate with their corresponding Siteminder webagents using inter process communication on the same box.

Now when I execute ipcs command to look for semaphores and sharedmem objects, it displays "all" the objects and I am not sure which ones to remove using the ipcrm command.

Is there a way to display just the ones that are being used by a specific apache instance?

I know a better option would have been to have 3 different app ids for the apache instances than 1.

Comment: `ipcs -p` will show you creators' PIDs.  Why do you want to remove them though?

Comment: Thanks!  ipcrm would be used to remove any semaphores or sharedmem objects that are left over in case of abnormal shutdown